# I am newbie here,I need some help in retrieving one particular use using a userid, how do we do that as per below code?

Tags: solidity, remix

```
struct Rider{
    //address riderAddr;
    uint rider_Id;
    bytes32 Rname;
    bool set;
}

mapping(address => Rider) public riders;

function registerRider(address _riderAddr, uint _riderId, bytes32 _riderName) public {
    Rider storage rider = riders[_riderAddr];
    //Already registered or not!
    require(!rider.set);
    //store rider data record
    riders[_riderAddr] = Rider({
        rider_Id: _riderId,
        Rname: _riderName,
        set: true
    });
}
```

Comment: do you want to find a rider by his id?

Comment: @BadrBellaj - Yes, I want to retrieve the whole list of array in one function viewRiders() first. Thank you very much for any help in advance!

Comment: you can't return a mapping in a function !!